# How do I disconnect debugger from devices in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Eclipse I use this button:

[image]

I didn't found anything similar in Android Studio. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I can still unplug and re-èplug the USB connector...

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Run" Tool Window located near the bottom left that you can bring up.  This will have a "Close" button to disconnect.

You can also get to the Run tool window by going to **View -> Tool Windows -> Run (Alt + 4)**